# Graph in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am using beamer and I need to create a slide with a graph. I tried to create it, but I have a problem my code:

```
\begin{frame}
 \begin{block} {Undirected graph 
}  

A graph  G=(V,E)  with a set of vertex V=$\left \{ v_{1},v_{2}, ... ,v_{n} \right \}$ and a set of edge (arc) E=$\left \{ e_{1},e_{2}, ... ,e_{m} \right \}$ is called undirected graph or (digraph) if each edge e$_{k}$ is an unorder pair (v$_{i}$,v$_{j}$).
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=3em, row sep=8ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt] (M) {%
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-4pt]v$_{1}$}] (V1){}; & & &\node[mypoint, label={right:v$_{2}$}] (V2) {};\\};
\draw(V2)--(V1);
\end{tikzpicture} 
 \end{block} 

\end{frame}
```

[image]

We can see on the graph that the vertices don't connect perfectly.

Comment: Does `\begin{frame}[fragile]` help? If not, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell beamer that this frame contains fragile command by using `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{block}{Undirected graph}  
        A graph  $G=(V,E)$ with a set of vertex $V=\left \{ v_{1},v_{2}, ... ,v_{n} \right \}$ and a set of edge (arc) $E=\left \{ e_{1},e_{2}, ... ,e_{m} \right \}$ is called undirected graph or (digraph) if each edge e$_{k}$ is an unordered pair (v$_{i}$,v$_{j}$).

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[column sep=3em, row sep=8ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt] (M) {%
               \node[label={[left,xshift=-4pt]v$_{1}$}] (V1){}; & & &\node[label={right:v$_{2}$}] (V2) {};\\
            };
            \draw(V2)--(V1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{block} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `ampersand replacement=\&` for the `matrix` is another option.